# How to show this functional is convex

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let M be bounded sequences space.
>
> $P(x)=\sup_n|x_n|$   ,$\quad x=(x_1,x_2,x_3...,x_n...)$
>
> $P:M\rightarrow \Bbb R^+$ is convex homogeneous functional.

Im not sure but it is homogeneous already because $\alpha \in R, P(\alpha x)=\sup_n|\alpha x_n|= \alpha \sup_n| x_n| $

and convexity:

$P(x)=\sup_n|x_n|,\quad x=(x_1,x_2,x_3...,x_n...)$

$P(y)=\sup_|y_n|,\quad y=(y_1,y_2,y_3...,y_n...), $

and $x+y=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2..x_n+y_n+..), $

there is i $\in N,x_i+y_i+\epsilon>  P(x+y)\ge x_i+y_i$

and for any $i\in N,x_i+y_i\le P(x)+P(y)$

How to continue ? Can we say for $\epsilon \to 0^+,P(x+y)\le P(x)+P(y) ?$

Comment: Convexity follows from positive homogeneity and sub-additivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show $P(x+y) \le P(x)+P(y)$.

You have $|x_i+y_i| \le |x_i|+|y_i| \le P(x) + P(y)$

Now take the $\sup$ of the left hand side to get the result.

You need to be careful with homogeneity, you have
$P(\alpha x) = \sup_i |\alpha x_i| = |\alpha| \sup_i |x_i| = |\alpha| P(x)$.
That is, it is positive homogeneous but not homogeneous.

Combining the two, if $\lambda \in [0,1]$, then
$$P(\lambda x+ (1-\lambda)y) \le P(\lambda x) + P((1-\lambda)y)=
\lambda P(x) + (1-\lambda) P(y)$$
hence $P$ is convex.

Comment: thanks. is this because for any i, $|x_i|+|y_i|\ge |x_i+y_i|$ so $|x_i|+|y_i| \ge sup|x_i+y_i|=P(x+y)$?

Comment: No. Follow the reasoning above. You have $|x_i| \le P(x)$ for any $i$ and same for $y$. The triangle inequality gives $|x_i+y_i| \le |x_i|+|y_i|$. Upper bound the right hand side first, then take the $\sup$.

Comment: Two issues: In your proof of homogeneity you have $\sup_n|\alpha x_n|= \alpha \sup_n| x_n|$ which is incorrect (take $\alpha=-1$ for example). Second, take $y=0, x=(0,1,0,...)$, Then $|x_1|+|y_1| \ge |x_1+y_1|$ of course, but $0=|x_1|+|y_1| \not\ge \sup_i |x_i+y_i| = 1$.